# Exception catching in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem with Exception catching in my Laravel 4 application.
I have a route like this `Route::get('/articles/edit/{id}', 'ArticlesController@edit')->where('id', '[0-9]+');`

Now if I go to `localhost:8000/articles/edit/6`, it works fine, but if I go to `localhost:8000/articles/edit/6a` it fails where clause because it has characters other than numbers, and throws `NotFoundHttpException`.

I have tried to catch this exception from inside edit function as well as from routes file, but no luck. Since I am just beginning with Laravel 4 i hope to find some help here since google didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom handlers for a `NotFoundHttpException` by using `App::missing`. From the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors):

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```